# How to Save Data without Page Reloading on Dropdown SelectedIndexChanged Event

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to update a DataTable on selection Index Changed event of DropdownList.

What I want is when I select/change dropDownList Item, the Selected Value should be saved into the database without Page refresh(without AutoPostback).

Comment: `DataTable` <>`DataBase`. Can you show what you have?

Comment: if you want to change your server created data according to a selection/value given from the client - you will have to post anything to the server! You may decide between partial postback or full page postback - but in the end, the server needs to know!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set `AutoPostback` to true.
But you can use an update panel to do a partial PostBack and not refresh the complete page.

[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Use it like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" >      
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
      <asp:ListItem>item 1</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem>item 2</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```